# chrome extension manager

Tags: google-chrome, browser-addons, plugins

Is there any google chrome extension that lets you manage other extensions?So that you can disable and enable them by just one click
Because I have many extensions installed in my chrome browser but I do not use them everytime. So I disable them, then enable them later using the bookmark with this address:

```
chrome://extensions/
```

Comment: so what is your problem then? you want an extension which mimics the built-in extension manager? or you just want to call the built-in extension manager faster?

Comment: Even if you had an addon to do this, it would still require a few clicks.  Why not just use the extension manager with a bookmark as you are now?

Comment: yep, just wondering if there is an extension like that

Answer (score 1):

[Disable All Extensions Plus](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ejhdjfmkegkpenillofhpmikailkjpkb#) now does this:

> Disable all extensions in one click, or enable all extensions in one click.
>   you also can enable or disable or uninstall the extensions one by one.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like fast enable/disable or opening extension/app options pages via the keyboard, you can use [Ferro: The Keyboard Interface to Chrome](http://www.getferro.com)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no extension like that.

How about [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/)? It's useful anytime you want to automate a process but there is no API you can easily use.